# How to get rid of blood/iron taste when cooking beef curry?

Tags: beef

I am trying to cook beef curry with the cold cut of beef. I cooked first 30 mins in pressure cooker, and now I've set at about one and a half hours on the pan and it still has blood taste. How long am I supposed to cook it for? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The veins of mammals contain blood. The muscle of animals contain hemoglobin which is a part of blood. Even if you eat your steak raw. You are not consuming blood. Abatoirs hang carcasses for up to a month so the blood can drain out of the meat.

Comment: @NeilMeyer -- actually muscles contain myoglobin, and blood contains hemoglobin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, marinating the beef for 1-2 hours before cooking can really help. Using yogurt, lemon juice, or vinegar as the marinade tenderizes the meat and pulls out some of that iron-rich myoglobin that makes beef taste bloody.

Next, be sure to simmer the curry nice and slow for 2-3 hours after pressure cooking. That extended gentle simmering lets the flavors blend together well and makes the meat fall-apart tender.

When the curry is simmering, throw in some tomatoes, tamarind, lime juice, vinegar - anything acidic, really. The acids react with those metallic iron compounds in the meat and mellow them out. I also like to toss in some chopped white potatoes near the end. Let them simmer for a bit and they'll soak up any leftover iron flavors. Just give the potatoes a gentle stir before serving so they distribute that goodness throughout.

Oh, and skim off the fat and foam during simmering. The scummy stuff on top holds a lot of impurities that can taste metallic. Use stainless steel or enameled pots and pans, not cast iron. The iron from the cookware can leak into the food and make it taste bloody.

And load up on the aromatics! Garlic, ginger, onions, cloves, cumin, coriander - they'll cover up any iron taste with their yummy flavors.

Comment: this looks very AI-generated

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: Again, feeding your answer back to the LLM with a prompt saying "rewrite this informally" is not actually going to make it less obvious or make it correct or coherent. For instance, the first paragraph suggests that myoglobin is positive because it gives beef a distinctive bloody taste. That is partly correct. The last paragraph contradicts it by saying that you do *not* want the beef to taste "bloody."

Comment: You know, I think that comment might not have been written by ChatGPT. Progress?

Answer (score 1):

That iron taste you get from the beef might be due to the myoglobin that's present in the meat. Myoglobin is a iron/oxygen binding protein that exists in the meat even after the blood is gone, which should already be the case when you buy/prepare the beef. Something you could try is searing the beef if it's a little gray, but something that might also help is marinating the beef in yogurt, which is really common for curry type dishes. It's pretty common to marinate chicken for biriyani in yogurt, so definately worth giving it a try.